# VLOOKUP search issue

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

Am having some issue using the VLOOKUP function in excel. Am a little new to excel and puzzled as to how to solve this problem. I have two excel sheets.

Sheet 1 looks like:

```
Col1   Col2    Col3
HIC    GSN     ND11
H1C    00214   0212107
C4I    07287   0214380
L1A    07731   0214501
```

Sheet 2 looks like:

```
Col1         Col2   Col3    Col4    Col5     Col6    Col7
Condition    HIC1   HIC1    HIC1    GSN      GSN     GSN
AMA          B60     B61    B62     02934   02935
ALD          H1A     H1C            04821   03473
HEC          W0A     W0B
```

The VLOOKUP formula that am using is:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,'Conditions.xlsx]Conditions'!$B$2:$BH$24,60,0)
```

Here B2 refers to Sheet 1, Column 1. Index Number 60 is a repeated Column 1 in Sheet 2. Is there a better way to lookup the COl1 and Col2 in Sheet one to extract the Conditions Columnin Sheet 2?

Any help would be great.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @AndrewL. Its shows #N/A

Comment: Is it intentional that you are looking for the value in the 60th column from B1? I would try an example using only column A and B to make sure it works. You probably don't need the file name in there- I'm assuming that's a typo?

Comment: Conditions sheet is a separate worksheet (table 2) that am checking the column 1 and column 2 of Table 1 against.

Comment: Worksheet or workbook? The form for selecting another worksheet in the same Workbook is- =Sheet2!A1

Comment: @AndrewL. I see what yo mean, that is a typo. It is a worksheet. In this case worksheet 2 (Sheet 2).

Comment: At this point I would agree with the poster below that this would be better suited for an Index, Match. Highlighting B through BH is probably not efficient and is open to all sorts of error. Either way you need to scale it down and get it to work with a small table before expanding to this kind of size.

Comment: @AndrewL, I ended up using an Index Match Function but restructured the table in Sheet 2 to make it easier to Index Match. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this: [How to use INDEX MATCH instead of VLOOKUP](https://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/how-use-index-match-instead-vlookup)

> But what happens if you want to look from right to left? VLOOKUP simply can't do that. INDEX/MATCH can.

Comment: I read up on Using Index and Match in Excel. What am trying to find is if instead of giving the match function one column at a time to index, for eg. INDEX(Classes!$A$2:$A$38,MATCH(B3,Classes!$B$2:$B$38,0)) , If I can enter an entire table in the match function, like INDEX(Classes!$A$2:$A$38,MATCH(B3,Classes!$B$2:$AT$38,0)). Hope this makes some sense.